# What is the probability of getting single 4 when three dices are rolled?

Tags: probability

As per my understanding, the answer will be the following:

```
A=1/6*5*6*5/6 B=5/6*1*6*5/6 C=5/6*5*6*1/6
```

p= P(a)+P(b)+P(c)
=75/216

Please verify if this is the right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216$ equally likely outcomes, when we throw 3 dice.

The probabilty of rolling a 4 on a die is ${1 \over 6}$.

The probabily of rolling something other than a 4 on a die is ${5 \over 6}$.

The probability of 4, not 4, and not 4 is
$$
{1 \over 6} \times {5 \over 6} \times {5 \over 6} = {25 \over 216}
$$

There are three different dice and "not 4" can happen in any of these three dice.

So, the required probability is
$$
{}^3C_1 \ {25 \over 216} = 3 \times {25 \over 216} = {75 \over 216}
$$

Comment: +1 But $3C1$ is more in accordance with: "..."not 4" can happen in any of these three dice..." than $3C2$.

Comment: You are 100% correct - I edited my answer - Thanks a lot.